# Does cube of ODI support OLAP operations like dicing, drilling, pivoting

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-data-integrator

I am a newbie in ODI. I have installed ODI 12c and created a data cube in it. After mapping the data cube, it is just added into the Oracle database like a simple table. I am wondering how the cube helps us to run queries very fast and in low time.
I have searched a lot and found that OLAP cube's Operations are Dicing, Drilling, Pivoting, ...

Would you please guide me on how to drill, dice, and pivot on the cube which is created in ODI?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ODI it's a tool that integrates data. The operation of Dicing, Drilling, Pivoting and so on, are operations that are made on a reporting tool such as Oracle OLAP.

You can't do that in ODI.
You could see [in this page](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/odi/develop/cubes_dimensions.htm#ODIDG9949) all the details rearding ODI Cubes.

EDIT 1, based on comment:

Due to the fact that when you create a Cube, you need to specify a datastore and dimensions(and also when create a dimension you need to specify a datastore) it means that a Cube have a phisical table behind.

Please [read here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/odi/develop/cubes_dimensions.htm#ODIDG9937) about dimensions and then about Cubes.

Very sort extraction from the links:

- A cube is a set of measures grouped together that have similar dimensionality. The axes of the cube contain dimension values and the body of the cube contains measure values.
- A dimension is a structure that organizes data. For example, a products dimension organizes data about products including product information, product categories and its sub-categories. A dimension consists of a set of levels and a set of hierarchies defined over these levels.

Hope that this answer helps you,
Florin!

Comment: Dear @F.Lazarescu, thanks. ODI cube is like a simple table in the database. I am wondering how the cube helps us to run queries very fast and in low time. Could you please guide me on how I can prove that running a query on the ODI cube is very fast? In fact, when running a query on the cube, does the cube run the query on the fly or have the pre-computed data?

Comment: Dear @M_Gh, please check my EDIT 1 from above and read creafully the link attached.

Comment: Dear @F.Lazarescu, thank you for your answer. I had been read the link before. I explain my situation in the new question about using Cube or not. Would you please take a look at this post: (https://stackoverflow.com/q/64319399/6640504)